# CPP Class Write-Protect Member

Tags: c++, class, constants, member

I have a C++ base class with a private std::map, `query_map` that is filled with new'd pointers on construction. In the destructor, I go through and delete all of the pointers to avoid memory leaks. Derived classes will be implementing a pure virtual function from the base class, and I want the implementations of this function to have read-access to `query_map` but not write access (as doing so will cause the destructor to seg-fault). Naturally I thought of making the pure virtual function const, but that locks out all member variables as well as non-const member functions, when really I want to only make `query_map` const. I can't use C++11 or higher due to our target platform and cross compiler.

Is making the entire function const really my only option?

Comment: What are you trying to say? It would be better to paste some code!

Comment: Did you even read it? It's not a problem with my code, it's a problem with choosing the right abstractions and protections for my code...

Comment: The name of the variable (`query_map`) sounds like a method name! I was confused!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `query_map` a private field, and provide a protected accessor function that returns a const reference to it:

```
private:
    std::map<...> query_map;

protected:
    std::map<...> const & get_query_map() const { return query_map; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Provide access to query_map through a const getter function.